# Unnable to pushing buttons in the screen generated by JQuery Mobile,during using for a while

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

I incorporated the following cords for a certain reason.

```
    $(document).on('pageshow', '#certain-page', function (e) {
              $(window).trigger('resize')
    });
```

First, nable to operate it commonly.
But unnable to pushing buttons and the screen was freezed during using for a while.
Probably,this occur in iOS, and not in Windows.
How can I avoid this phenomenon?